# Targetting CiviCRM input field labels with css

Tags: css

I can see how to hide an input field using custom css, but I cannot figure out how to hide the specific label for that field. All the labels on the contact form seem to have the same selector. I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an attribute selector in css, for example

> label[for="middle_name"] {   display:none; }

For more info see:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors
or
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599627/how-to-select-label-for-email-in-css

Does even work in IE, from version 8.